# qtconfig tool for Qt 5?

Tags: arch-linux, qt

I've just installed QT 5 in Arch Linux, but only `qtconfig` doesn't work:

```
%> qtconfig
qtconfig: could not exec '/usr/lib/qt/bin/qtconfig': No such file or directory
```

Yes, there's no such file, not even `/usr/lib/qt5/bin/qtconfig`

Any ideas where to locate it? I need to adjust the font of `smplayer`, which is linked with QT 5 libraries now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

qtconfig no longer exist in Qt5. Qt5 applications will use the current desktop settings by default, but it doesn't work perfectly. For instance I'm using XFCE and it doesn't automatically set the style to Gtk.

The style can be set with the `-style` command line option, for instance `-style=gtk` . Or you can use a specific [Qt stylesheet](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/stylesheet.html) with `-stylesheet`. [You can see the available options in QApplication documentation.](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qapplication.html#QApplication) Also :

> You can also set the style for all Qt applications by setting the QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE environment variable.

For smplayer, you can change the default font and style used in the menu Option > Preferences > Interface.

Comment: Sadly, QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE does not seem to work for me. I'm using keepassx, and when launched as `keepassx -style=gtk` it works, but `QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=gtk keepassx` does not. I've also tried exporting the environment variable elsewhere, and it still does not get picked up :(

Answer (score 6):

The solution that worked best for me is `qt5ct`, which is currently available in the standard Arch community packages. It's a DE-independant Qt5 configuration utility similar to the old qtconfig.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/qt#Configuration_of_Qt5_apps_under_environments_other_than_KDE_Plasma

Answer (score 5):

this here does its job: https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/lxqt-config/

not packaged, afaik: http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/Qt5+Configuration+Tool?content=168066

Comment: Your first link appears to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

See  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/qt

`Qt` packages do not provide the usual `bin` (e.g. `qmake`) in `/usr/bin` anymore.

Instead `-qt5`, `-qt4` and `-qt3` symlinks are provided (e.g. `qmake-qt5`, `qmake-qt4`, `qmake-qt3`).